# Read() return value and EOF

Tags: c

I read that EOF defined in  as:

```
#define EOF (-1)
```

so why read return value is:

> **RETURN VALUES:**
>        If successful, the number of bytes actually read is returned.  Upon reading end-of-file,
>        zero is returned.  Otherwise, a -1 is returned and the global variable errno is set to
>        indicate the error.

why it doesn't return -1 upon reading end-of-file?

Comment: `EOF` is a standard C macro. The [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html#tag_16_474) function is a POSIX standard function. It behaves quite differently from e.g. [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Comment: At design time, it has been decided that reading zero bytes *is* actually successful – i.e., not an error. But do note that stating "upon reading end-of-file" is wrong: there is no "end of file" code to read, and mentally parsing this *as if* there is such a code will cause problems with some functions.

Comment: get it, thank you both

Comment: The `-1` `EOL` (typically) is defined to be is unrelated to the `-1` returned by `read()` on error. `EOF` ought to be negative, not necessarily `-1`, although it mostly ever is.

Comment: In general, there is absolutely no sound rationale why all them old Unix functions were designed the way they were. Someone smoked some unmentionable substances, then casually created a function in a few minutes. BAM - industry standard for the following 50 years. Then during ISO C library standardization, they took all functions from Unix, placed them in a hat, and picked a few hundred randomly. Fortunately, `read` did not come up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trying to answer "why" for a decision made in the 1980s belongs on retrocomputing now.

Comment: note that in Standard C EOF may be any negative integer value, not necessarily -1

Answer (score 1):

The macro `EOF` is defined in `<stdio.h>` by Standard C and is used by functions that use standard I/O streams (`FILE *`).

Functions such as `read()` are part of POSIX, and are declared in the `<unistd.h>` header.  They are unrelated to the standard I/O streams and do not use `EOF` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `EOF` macro is used with functions that read a single character from a file or standard input and return it as a return value (for example, `getchar()` or `fgetc()`). If the input is empty, then such functions return `EOF` instead of a character to tell you that no characters can be read.

You mentioned the `read()` function, which reads a sequence of characters into the buffer specified as an argument. In this case, an `EOF` value is not required because this function return the number of characters read.

Comment: `EOF` is used by functions such as `scanf()` that do not read single characters in general (though it can, of course, be used to read a single character). Your use of "if the input is empty" is ambiguous. For example, if the input is a pipe but there is no data to be read, the functions do _not_ return `EOF`; they hang waiting until there is some input, or the system determines that no process has the pipe open for writing (at which point, the systems indicates `EOF` to the processes waiting to read from the pipe — though that is normally done in the first place by `read()` returning 0).

Comment: You're right. But it seems to me that for an initial understanding it is not necessary to overload the situation with additional details. After all, as I understand it, the question was about the motives of the initial approach, and not about the final implementation.